# Can I update the records in AWS Timestream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

Can I update the records data in AWS timestream? From what I have read, delete & update operations are not permitted in timestream. Is there any workarounds to perform the update operation on the timestream records?

Comment: You can upsert data in AWS Timestream https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/writes.html#writes.writing-data-inserts-upserts but you can't delete records. This means that you can modify the *Measure* value of your record but not he *Dimensions* since they are part of the primary key identifying your unique record

Answer (score 3):

As long as all dimensions and the timestamps are the same, if call the method .version() with a number higher than the one in storage, (like version = 1 on db and update with .version(2)), yes, it's possible to update.
Please, refer to the article linked in the comments of MaFF.
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/writes.html#writes.writing-data-inserts-upserts)

Comment: To clarify, the version is a parameter on the Record sent to the write API but it's not a measure value (column) that you need to model. See the Timestream API docs for a Record which defines the version parameter, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/API_Record.html.

One trick they show in their samples is to use the epoch seconds as the version to ensure later writes always upsert.

Comment: @NadirSidi I have posted a question, please take a look at it, it doesnt work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72088242/how-should-i-update-a-field-of-a-record-in-amazon-timestream