# How should I update a field of a record in Amazon Timestream?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-timestream

I am trying to update a field in a record in Timestream but it keeps inserting new record instead.
Here is my code:

```
$dimensions= [];

$dimensions[] = [
 'Dimensions' => [
    [
        'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
        'Name' => 'id',
        'Value' => '123456',
    ],
    [
        'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
        'Name' => 'remark',
        'Value' => 'Remark test text',
    ],
  ],
];

$query = [
'CommonAttributes' => [
    'MeasureName' => 'table_cnt',
    'MeasureValue' => 'table_cnt',
    'MeasureValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
    'Time' => '1651501311000', 
    'TimeUnit' => 'MILLISECONDS',
    'Version' => 1,
],
'DatabaseName' => 'mydb',
'Records' => $dimensions,
'TableName' => 'table',
];

$db->WriteRecords($query);
```

and now here how I try to upsert the same record inserted above:

```
$dimensions= [];

$dimensions[] = [
 'Dimensions' => [
    [
        'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
        'Name' => 'id',
        'Value' => '123456',
    ],
    [
        'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
        'Name' => 'remark',
        'Value' => 'New Remark test text', // new text
    ],
  ],
];

$query = [
'CommonAttributes' => [
    'MeasureName' => 'table_cnt',
    'MeasureValue' => 'table_cnt',
    'MeasureValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
    'Time' => '1651501311000',      // same time 
    'TimeUnit' => 'MILLISECONDS',
    'Version' => 2,                 // changed to version 2 when upserting
],
'DatabaseName' => 'mydb',
'Records' => $dimensions,
'TableName' => 'table',
];

$db->WriteRecords($query);
```

I dont understand what am I doing wrong here, and the lack of documentations and samples is making it even more difficult to find out!
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Timestream, the dimensions together with the time are a "key" for upserting. If you have different dimensions, it will insert a new record with the new dimensions.
The version field is only used if all dimensions and time are exactly the same. Then, the measures will be updated with the new values.
You can find better information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/data-modeling.html#data-modeling-dimensionsmeasures, under the "Choosing dimensions", the first bullet point.

Comment: Here's the link to the relevant documentation-- see the first bullet point under the "Choosing dimensions" sub-heading: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/data-modeling.html#data-modeling-dimensionsmeasures

For completeness, the measure name is also considered for uniqueness.

Comment: I dont think I get it. So you are saying that Dimensions' values should all be the same ? If yes, then what are we even updating there? I mean I am actually trying to update a Dimension as you can see in my question.

Comment: @NadirSidi question was, how do I update?

Comment: @showtime What you update is the Metrics/Measurements. The dimensions are basically the metadata for that metrics and they cannot be updated.

Comment: @EduardoEliasSaléh just found that out. I am getting this error: measureValues (list) not supported for BOOL, DOUBLE, VARCHAR and BIGINT data types. But their doc clearly shows that they DO support those data types: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-timestream-write-2018-11-01.html#writerecords

Comment: @EduardoEliasSaléh I would highly appreciate your help now

Comment: @showtime, When you store something in Timestream it partitions by the dimension names & values, measure names, and time. If you change the dimension value, it treats that like a new record. You could logically treat it as an upsert in your query/application logic, but it won't be stored as such.

Also, I've seen the error you're reporting versus the docs. In my case, it was a mismatch between the latest boto3 version, which is what the docs are written to, and the default boto3 version in the lambda environment. I would check your boto3 version.

Comment: @showtime I don't know if I understood your problem but, AFAIK, measures can only be, as the doc you linked said, 'DOUBLE|BIGINT|VARCHAR|BOOLEAN|TIMESTAMP|MULTI' ... not a list. In fact, I also had problems with lists and Timestream is not meant at all to store lists, not on dimensions nor on measures. If you need that, then, please, reconsider your choices, as cardinality is a key to keep performance on querying/read.

Comment: @EduardoEliasSaléh I am not trying to store lists, I am trying to store values that can be updated in the future. How can I do that besides with measureValues?!

Comment: @EduardoEliasSaléh I have posted that problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72098121/writing-record-with-measurevalues-error-please-use-measurevalue-to-send-the-dat

Comment: @NadirSidi I am talking about this issue I have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72098121/writing-record-with-measurevalues-error-please-use-measurevalue-to-send-the-dat