# Writing record with MeasureValues error: Please use measureValue to send the data

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I am writing to Timestream a list of dimensions and a list of measureValues but I keep getting this error:

> "Message":"measureValues (list) not supported for BOOL, DOUBLE, VARCHAR and BIGINT data types. Please use measureValue to send the data."

Here is my code:

```
$dimensions= [];

$dimensions[] = [
 'Dimensions' => [
    [
        'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
        'Name' => 'id',
        'Value' => '123456',
    ],
  ],
'MeasureValues' => [
    [
        'Name' => 'remark',
        'Type' => 'VARCHAR',
        'Value' => 'Some test text',
    ],
  ]
];

$query = [
'CommonAttributes' => [
    'MeasureName' => 'table_cnt',
    'MeasureValue' => 'table_cnt',
    'MeasureValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
    'Time' => '1651501311000', 
    'TimeUnit' => 'MILLISECONDS',
    'Version' => 1,
],
'DatabaseName' => 'mydb',
'Records' => $dimensions,
'TableName' => 'table',
];

$db->WriteRecords($query);
```

According to AWS documentation here ([Parameter Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-timestream-write-2018-11-01.html#writerecords)) it clearly shows that the supported data types are "DOUBLE|BIGINT|VARCHAR|BOOLEAN|TIMESTAMP|MULTI". If you check a bit down below under "MeasureValues" bulletpoint, it says the opposite: "*This is only allowed for type MULTI*." . Eitherway, I did try to change the type to MULTI but it still throws the same error.

Comment: I would suggest removing the 'MeasureValue' from the 'CommonAttributes' and changing the 'MeasureValueType' from 'VARCHAR' to 'MULTI' also on the 'CommonAttributes' and give it a try.

Comment: @EduardoEliasSaléh saved my day, thanks! Can you post an answer with a bit more details ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're expecting to use the format

```
[
    'Name' => 'remark',
    'Type' => 'VARCHAR',
    'Value' => 'Some test text',
],
```

as input to measures, you need to declare the MeasureValueType as 'MULTI' and not send a MeasureValue on the body of the request. In your example, the final request would be like this:

```
$dimensions= [];

$dimensions[] = [
 'Dimensions' => [
    [
        'DimensionValueType' => 'VARCHAR',
        'Name' => 'id',
        'Value' => '123456',
    ],
  ],
'MeasureValues' => [
    [
        'Name' => 'remark',
        'Type' => 'VARCHAR',
        'Value' => 'Some test text',
    ],
  ]
];

$query = [
'CommonAttributes' => [
    'MeasureName' => 'table_cnt',
     // Removed MeasureValue from here as it's MULTI
    'MeasureValueType' => 'MULTI', // <- changed from 'VARCHAR' to 'MULTI'
    'Time' => '1651501311000', 
    'TimeUnit' => 'MILLISECONDS',
    'Version' => 1,
],
'DatabaseName' => 'mydb',
'Records' => $dimensions,
'TableName' => 'table',
];

$db->WriteRecords($query);
```

As a reference, I would suggest you to try it first without the CommonAttributes, as you're inserting only one record, like I demonstrate on this article: https://du7.medium.com/aws-timestream-multi-measures-71b41c089af4

Comment: thanks, I just found out another downside of timestream, when updating I need to actually insert ALL other measure values (of course beside dimensions, time and incremented version). It sucks that I have to pass all the data to just update one of them.